# JQuery Cookie expire after 1 minute

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Do anyone know how do i set cookie expire after 1 minute?I had set cookie expire inside my code but it's seem like not working ... can anyone help me to fix that ?It's better to write full code or Fiddle for me  , cause I don't know code sorry . Thanks in advance for help . 
Here my Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Garfrey/3Lzytvqy/4/

```
function showHide(setCookie) {
    var shID = $(this).data("showhide")
      , $shEl = $("#" + shID)
      , $showHide = $("#" + shID + '-show')
      ;

    if ($shEl.is(":hidden")) {
        if (setCookie !== false) {
            jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + shID, 1);
        }
        $showHide.hide();
        $shEl.show();
    } else {
        if (setCookie !== false) {
            jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + shID, 0);
        }
        $showHide.show();
        $shEl.hide();
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example-show").on("click", showHide);
    if (jQuery.cookie("showhide-" + "example") == '1') {
        showHide.call($("#example-show").get(0), false);
    }
});

var date = new Date();
var minutes = 1;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: date });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code:
I don't know the expected behaviour, therefore this is as much as I can help.

I am sure if you trace below code, you can integrate it easily with your code.
Make sure you include jquery cookie js.

```
$('div#set_cookie').click(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (5 * 1000)); // 5 seconds
    $.cookie('test', 1, { expires: date });

    $('div#log').html('<b>cookie has been set! expires : '+date+'</b>');
});

$('div#check_cookie').click(function(){
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("test");
    if (cookieValue){
        $('div#log').html('valid cookie');
    }else{
        $('div#log').html('expired cookie');
    }

});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1vut0ro/)**

Comment: HI taesu , thanks for giving me this , your code is work .. but I din't know how to merge inside with my function . Can you let me know what I need to change for merging my function or do me a Fiddle ? brilliant thanks!